# Не всегда проходит подключение к домену авторизации (ldap)

Tags: java, ldap

Суть в том, если домен авторизации написан криво, ошибка авторизации возникает моментально. Если же он написан правильно, или авторизует меня сразу же, или виснет секунд 20-30 и сообщает, что не дождался отклика от домена.

Можете подсказать в чем может быть загвоздка, или откуда начать копать?

upd: Создается отдельное приложение на Java. К сожалению что-то делать с настройками домена я не могу.

```
private static LdapContext getConnection(String login, String pass, String serverName, String domainName){
        //Склеиваем логин и домен
        Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
        String principalName = login + "@" + domainName;
        //Добавляем логин и пароль к конфигуратору
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principalName);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
        //Добавляем адрес сервера к конфигуратору
        String ldapURL = "ldap://" + ((serverName==null)? domainName : serverName + "." + domainName) ;
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        props.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", 120000+"");
        props.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connection.timeout", 0+"");
        //Пробуем залогинится

        try{
            return new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
        }
        catch(javax.naming.CommunicationException e){

            System.err.println(e+" Failed to connect to " + domainName + ((serverName==null)? "" : " through " + serverName));
            return null;

        }
        catch(NamingException e){

            System.err.println("Failed to authenticate " + login + "@" + domainName + ((serverName==null)? "" : " through " + serverName));
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Сделано по образцу, serverName - пустой.

Ошибка:

```
javax.naming.communicationexception: domen.ru:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect] Filed to connect to domen.ru
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй покопать размер коннекшн пула для авторизации. 
На WLS у меня примерно такая же ситуация судя по описанию. Не хватало коннекшенов для того чтобы достучатся к провайдеру аутентификации. Решил так:

1. В параметрах провайдера аутентификации (WLConsole > Security Realms > myrealm > AD Provider) на вкладке Configuration > Provider Specific в параметре Connection Pool Size указать значение соотвествующее максимальному одновременному количеству одновременных аутентификаций пользователей
2. Нажать кнопку сохранить и применить изменения
3. В файле конфигурации окружения домена ($MW_HOME/domains/zp_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.sh) в параметрах запуска EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES добавить ключ  -Dweblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPDelegatePoolSize=275
4. В файле конфигурации OVD ($MW_HOME/domains/zp_domain/config/fmwconfig/ovd/default) в тегах относящихся к AD провайдеру  и  указать 275
5. Перезапустить админсервер и все managed-сервера этого домена

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но тут скорее проблемы на уровне моего приложения, т.к. другие приложения и\или сами компьютеры авторизуются без каких-либо проблем. (и с сервером я врятли что-то смогу сделать) Сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: Добавьте еще стектрейс ошибки, при неудачно аутентификации, если есть.

Comment: Есть только сама ошибка (полное описание). Как снова поймаю ошибку - добавлю полный стэктрейс.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить параметры запуска вашего приложения или сервера:  -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize=20 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize=10 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=300000 Подробнее можно в документации посмотреть [LDAP JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html#POOL)

Comment: Увы не помогло. Я бы проигнорировал это проблему (она возникает стихийно и не часто), но если уж возникнет, то авторизация не работает минут 20-30. А это уже проблема.

Comment: При возникновении проблемы в этом приложении, в других приложениях работает авторизация через этот домен?

Comment: Увы на тестируемых машинках это не проверить, но есть следующий факт:  <br/>Проблема в контроллере, судя по всему он иногда попадает на контроллер не поддерживающий ldap авторизацию. Т.к. если ее указать руками - все работает исправно. В итоге все вылилось в другой [вопрос.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444101/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)