# Получить текущий домен и контроллер от него?

Tags: java, ldap

В поисках ответа на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441923/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-ldap) возникла мысля....

Я знаю как получить просто адрес домена, в котором установлен ПК:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + удалить имя ПК. (скопировать не получится, а переписывать лень)
```

А вот как получить корректный контроллер для аутентификации?
Может если я ручками его выцеплю, то и ошибка возникать не будет.

UPD: Как мне найти контроллеры на которых АКТИВНА авторизация ldap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно нашел ответ на англоязычном "стэке".
Вот этот код выцепляет стрингу адреса вместе с контроллером и портом:

```
/**
 * Detect the default LDAP server
 * @return server:port or null
 */
 public static String getDefaultLdapHost() {
    try {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable();
        env.put( "java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory" );
        DirContext dns = new InitialDirContext( env );

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String domain = address.getCanonicalHostName();

        if( domain.equals( address.getHostAddress() ) ) {
            //domain is a ip address
            domain = getDnsPtr( dns );
        }

        int idx = domain.indexOf( '.' );
        if( idx < 0 ) {
            //computer is not in a domain? We will look in the DNS self.
            domain = getDnsPtr( dns );
            idx = domain.indexOf( '.' );
            if( idx < 0 ) {
                //computer is not in a domain
                return null;
            }
        }
        domain = domain.substring( idx + 1 );

        Attributes attrs = dns.getAttributes( "_ldap._tcp." + domain, new String[] { "SRV" } );

        Attribute attr = attrs.getAll().nextElement();
        String srv = attr.get().toString();

        String[] parts = srv.split( " " );
        return parts[3] + ":" + parts[2];
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Look for a reverse PTR record on any available ip address
 * @param dns DNS context
 * @return the PTR value
 * @throws Exception if the PTR entry was not found
 */
private static String getDnsPtr( DirContext dns ) throws Exception {
    Exception exception = null;
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface nif = interfaces.nextElement();
        if( nif.isLoopback() ) {
            continue;
        }
        Enumeration<InetAddress> adresses = nif.getInetAddresses();
        while(adresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress address = adresses.nextElement();
            if( address.isLoopbackAddress() || address instanceof Inet6Address) {
                continue;
            }
            String domain = address.getCanonicalHostName();
            if( !domain.equals( address.getHostAddress() ) && (domain.indexOf( '.' ) > 0) ) {
                return domain;
            }

            String ip = address.getHostAddress();
            String[] digits = ip.split( "\\." );
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append( digits[3] ).append( '.' );
            builder.append( digits[2] ).append( '.' );
            builder.append( digits[1] ).append( '.' );
            builder.append( digits[0] ).append( ".in-addr.arpa." );
            try {
                Attributes attrs = dns.getAttributes( builder.toString(), new String[] { "PTR" } );
                return attrs.get( "PTR" ).get().toString();
            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                exception = ex;
            }
        }
    }
    if( exception != null ) {
        throw exception;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No network");
}
```

!!!Перед вставкой проверяйте, он там где-то лишнюю точку ставит (вроде перед портом)